# How to use logging with python's fileConfig and configure the logfile filename

Tags: python, file, logging, console, python-logging

I have a logging configuration file for logging to console and a file with different formats and levels. In my python script I can load this configuration and basically console and file output are ok.

I set the file name in the config file as shown below.

Is it possible to set that file name in the python script itself?

**python code:**

```
# set up logging
logging.config.fileConfig(loginipath)
logger = logging.getLogger('sLogger')

# log something
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

**logging config file:**

```
[loggers]
keys=root,sLogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=fileFormatter,consoleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_sLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler
qualname=sLogger
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('logfile.log',)

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Answer (score 76):

Change your `handler_fileHandler` section like so:

```
[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('%(logfilename)s',)
```

and then add a `defaults` argument to the fileConfig call

```
logging.config.fileConfig(loginipath, defaults={'logfilename': '/var/log/mylog.log'})
```

Comment: I know this is old, but is it possible to specify the filename in the config file name and path rather than in the script that is calling it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484232/what-is-the-correct-way-of-configuring-pythons-logging-filehandler

Answer (score 15):

Both handlers worked for me:

(1)

```
logging.config.fileConfig( 'logging.ini' , disable_existing_loggers=False)


[handler_myhandler1]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=form01
args=('python.log', 'w')
```

(2)

```
logging.config.fileConfig( 'logging.ini' , disable_existing_loggers=False, defaults={ 'logfilename' : getSomeName() } )

[handler_myhandler2]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=form01
args=('%(logfilename)s','w')
```

after reading examples at https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html

Answer (score 1):

For those of you wanting to only specify the directory, not the filename, keep in mind you can use python expressions in the config file. So the config file should look something like:

```
[handler_myhandler2]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=form01
args=(os.path.join('%(logdirpath)s', 'yourfilename.log'),'w')
```

and your caller should look like:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(loginipath, defaults={'logdirpath': '/var/log'})
```

be mindfulf that the ConfigParser expects single forward slashes for filepaths.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `logging.config.dictConfig()` after `fileConfig()` and just setting the filename.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to set the file name. Thanks.