# Can I add environment variables to a python logger ini file configuration?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I want to add a customized log file directory using an environment variable in my file handler through a `log.ini file` used in a `logging.fileConfig()` function.

I had tried adding an environment variable in the following:

My logging.ini looks like this:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=fileFormatter,consoleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler, fileHandler
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('${LOG_DIRECTORY_ENV_VARIABLE}/logname.log',)
```

And I configure it using:

```
from logging.config import fileConfig

fileConfig(f"{BASE_PATH}/resources/logging.ini")
```

My code results that the directory to be: `path/to/file/${LOG_DIRECTORY_ENV_VARIABLE}/logname.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that there's a walk around to my question using an answer on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649664/how-to-use-logging-with-pythons-fileconfig-and-configure-the-logfile-filename)

Comment: Rather than posting a link to the thread, please link to the answer. Otherwise, there's ambiguity that dilutes the value of this answer.

Comment: actually, this is a much better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57820456/202698

Answer (score 0):

You can call python functions from `args`. As `os` is already imported in `logging` you can call `environ` without the use of `__import__('os').environ['']`.

```
...
[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fileFormatter
args=(f'{os.environ[
"LOG_DIRECTORY_ENV_VARIABLE"]}/logname.log',)
...
```