# Python logging creates empty log file

Tags: python, logging, logfile

I am trying to setup a logging configuration to use in my different modules. I have followed different tutorials and stackoverflow posts ([here](https://realpython.com/python-logging/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727420/using-logging-in-multiple-modules) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649664/how-to-use-logging-with-pythons-fileconfig-and-configure-the-logfile-filename)) to write logs in to a `project.log` file.

While the information is displayed correctly in the console, the `log.conf` is read correctly, the `project.log` is created but is not filled with the warning messages.

Here is how I proceeded:

The `log.conf` file used to write up the handlers and formatting:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,sLogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=fileFormatter,consoleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_sLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler
qualname=sLogger
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('%(logfilename)s', 'w')

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

In the `main.py` file:

```
import logging
import logging.config

def main():

    logging.config.fileConfig(fname='./log.conf', 
                                defaults={'logfilename': 'project.log')}, 
                                disable_existing_loggers=False)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    logger.warning('This is a message')
```

In my `module.py` file:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.warning('Example of a warning message')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem ! I didn't realize but when defining `handlers` in the `log.conf` file, the order of the handlers and formatters is important !

I changed the `log.conf` changed to:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,sLogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=consoleFormatter, fileFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler, fileHandler

[logger_sLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler, fileHandler
qualname=sLogger
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('%(logfilename)s','a')

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s


[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

NOTE the changed order between `consoleFormatter` and `fileHandler` in the `[formatters]` section.

The rest is working perfectly fine.

To make it easier to play around with I put it in a function (which is probably redundant I suppose):

```
def base_logger(path_conf, fname, savedir):
    '''
    Base logging function to be started once
    in the main script then used in every other
    modules.

    Args:
        - path_conf: str, path to the configuration
        file {log.conf}
        - fname: str, name of the saved log file
        - savedir: str, path of the saving directory

    Returns:
        - logging object to be used in the other scripts

    Example:
        In main.py:
            main():
                base_logger(paht_cong = './log.conf', fname='file', savedir='project)
        
        In module.py:
            # AFTER all the import
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # To ge the module name reported in the log file
            ...
            logger.error(f'Error message regarding variable {var}')

        The logger initialization {logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)},
         has to be done in every file that will use logging !

    '''
    logging.config.fileConfig(fname=path_conf,
                                defaults={'logfilename': os.path.join(savedir, f'{fname}.log')}, 
                                disable_existing_loggers=False)
```

I would add that the `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` has to be placed after all `imports` to make sure that the `module` name displayed in the log is not imported from other modules.