# Save log files in the user home directory

Tags: python, logging

I have a logging.conf [1] file to configure the logging in my python application.

```
...
[handler_file_log_handler]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simple
args=('/var/log/myapp/myapp.log',)
```

As you can see, I'm storing the log file in /var/log/myapp directory.

What I would like is to store it in the user (the user that manages the application) home directory (/home/myuser/.myapp/log). So, my question is:

What should I configure in my logging.conf in order to be able to save the log file of my python application in the user home directory?

[1] - https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/logging.html#configuring-logging

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484232/what-is-the-correct-way-of-configuring-pythons-logging-filehandler

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass any Python expression as argument! Including one that finds the user's home!

```
args=(f'{os.path.expanduser("~")}/myapp.log',)
```

For Python <= 3.5 (no f-strings):

```
args=(os.path.expanduser("~") + '/myapp.log',)
```

---

For completeness, here is a minimal example (tested with 3.5 and 3.9):

**logging.conf**

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=fileLogHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileLogHandler

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s

[handler_fileLogHandler]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(os.path.expanduser("~") + '/myapp.log',)
```

**main.py**

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info('Testo')
```

---

Additional note:
I thought that passing `~/myapp.log` as path would work and let the OS take care of the expansion, which actually works in most places in Python. But inexplicably this does not work inside a `logging.conf` file!

```
args=('~/myapp.log',)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
    '/path/to/this/python/project/~/myapp.log'  # ???
```

Answer (score -1):

The user's home directory can be found (on any OS) using:

```
os.path.expanduser("~")
```

Comment: That's right. But, Does that instruction work in a logging.conf file? Does Python translate that instruction inside of a .conf file?